# how to save the values into database of three forms with one submit in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

hi i have three forms and i want to save the values of three forms with one submit button which is located outside of the three forms in php  i am using javascript to submit my form and now i want to save the data into my database.
here is my javascript

```
 function submit()
{
    document.form1.submit();
    document.form2.submit();
    document.form3.submit();

}
```

here is my php

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    browse("1213 1314");
    $gen1 = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(accode) AS maxcode FROM quotmain LIMIT 0,1 ") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($gen1) > 0) {
        $vvouch = mysql_fetch_assoc($gen1);
        $qvouch = $vvouch["maxcode"] + 1;
    } else{
        $qvouch = '1';
    }

    $a = 1;
    $vouchdt  = mydt($_POST["vouchdt"]); 
    $name     = $_POST["cmbparty"];
    $refno    = $_POST["refno1"];
    browse($refno);
    $attn     = $_POST["attn"];
    $subj     = $_POST["subject"];
    $msg      = $_POST["messsage"];
    $rem      = $_POST["rem"];
    $count    = $_POST["items"];
    $h        = $_POST["h"]; 
    $status   = $_POST["cmbstatus"];

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM quotdtl WHERE vouchno='$qvouch'") or die(mysql_error());

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $ord     = $_POST['ord_' . $i];
        $srno    = $_POST['srno_' . $i];
        $descrip = $_POST['descrip_' . $i];
        $unit    = $_POST['unit_' . $i];
        $rate = $_POST['rate_' . $i];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `quotdtl`(vouchno, orderby, srno, `descrip`, unit, rate)
                            VALUES('$qvouch', '$ord', '$srno', '$descrip', '$unit', '$rate')") or die(mysql_error());
    }

     mysql_query("DELETE FROM quotnotes WHERE vouchno='$qvouch'") or die(mysql_error());

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $h; $i++) {
        $notes = $_POST['notes' . $i];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `quotnotes`(vouchno, `notes`)
                            VALUES('$qvouch', '$notes')") or die(mysql_error());
    }   

    if ($addflag == 1) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `quotmain`(vouchno, `vouchdt`, `party`, refno, `attn`, `subject`, `message`, `rem1`, `status`, `username`)
                            VALUES($qvouch, '$vouchdt', '$name', '$refno', '$attn', '$subj', '$msg', '$rem', '$status','$_SESSION[username]')") or die(mysql_error());

        insmess();
        header("refresh: 1; quotation.php?mode=true");
     } else {
            $mvouch = $_POST["vouch"];
             mysql_query("UPDATE `quotmain` SET `vouchdt`='$vouchdt', `name`='$name', refno='$refno', `attn`='$attn', `subject`='$subj',
                                 `message`='$msg', `rem1`='$rem', `username`='$_SESSION[username]' WHERE vouchno = '$mvouch' ") or die(mysql_error());
             updmess();
             header("refresh: 1; menu.php?action=quotation");
     }

}
```

Comment: Dont use mysql_ commands, they are deprecated. Use something like mysqli or PDO.

Comment: ok sir will do that but for now can u help in showing that why my code is not working not:- the values comes from three different forms in the save part

Comment: Are the form targets different or same?

Comment: the targets are same the save part is wriiten on the same page

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put all your objects in one `<form>` tag. Since you are calling only one submit button.

Comment: Yes that is a resolution (walkaround type) to the problem.

Comment: no sir as per my requirement i want all the three forms different

Comment: or is der a way to specify the value from the values are coming form i mean can we specify thatfrm which form the valuesare coming form ?

Comment: are the forms on the same page? Since your objects have their unique `id`'s you can determine where the values are coming from.

Comment: how can i determine the values coming from?

Comment: The best way is making a prefix on your `id`'s. Like for example put `form1_`.

Answer (score 0):

**Ritual Warning:** Please do not use mysql_ functions, use mysqli_ or PDO interfaces instead.

This code:

```
function submit(){
    document.form1.submit();
    document.form2.submit();
    document.form3.submit();
}
```

Will not work if form targets are same.

In that case, you have to harvest the form datas via javaScript and better encode them into a JSON array then POST to server.

To access first forms form input value with id = 'SpecialInput1' use:

```
  var v1 = document.forms[0].SpecialInput.value; 
  // you can use form name also:
  var v1 = document.myFirstForm.SpecialInput.value;
```

Write a loop collecting the data into a Js object as f1Data = {"address":"nowhere", "name": "John", "surname":"doe" }...and f2data and f3Data then put them into an array : [f1data,f2data,f3data], then json encode them and post them to the server.

On the server json_decode the post data and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: but is der a way to specify in the $_POST of where are the values coming from

Comment: Of course... That depends on the data structure you build when you collect the data from forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit only one form at a time. In your case once you call form1.submit() the page navigates.

Using Ajax you can submit all the required forms.

Comment: but how can i save the values even if i use ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery post like below

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        $.post(this.action, $form.serialize());
    });
});
```

If above is not feasible, then provide different targets to your forms. This will open 2 new windows/tab when you hit on submit

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="post.php">
<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="post.php" target="_blank">
<form name="form3" id="form3" method="post" action="post.php" target="_blank1">
```

or, you can have 3 different hidden IFrames and specify target as IFrame in your forms

```
<iframe name='if1' id='if1' src='dummy.html' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='0' height='0'></iframe>
<iframe name='if2' id='if2' src='dummy.html' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='0' height='0'></iframe>
<iframe name='if3' id='if3' src='dummy.html' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='0' height='0'></iframe>
```

And then your forms should be

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="post.php" target="if1">
<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="post.php" target="if2">
<form name="form3" id="form3" method="post" action="post.php" target="if3">
```

Comment: Does everybody use JQuery everytime?

Comment: It has lots of APIs, third party plugins and easy to use. You can reduce a lot of efforts by using it. On top of these, they are compatible to mostly all browsers

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some workaround like this:

Use your javascript `submit()` function but instead of :

```
form1.submit();
form2.submit();
form3.submit();
```

You could iterate form2 and form3 and add the elements to the form1 like this :
(this code is not tested, it's just the concept)

```
for (element in form2.elements) {
     form1.elements['form2['+element['name']+']'] = element;
}
for (element in form3.elements) {
     form1.elements['form3['+element['name']+']'] = element;
}
form1.submit();
```

This way in your form1 you have all the data from other forms, and you can tell which form submitted which data, because form2 datas are in `$_POST['form2']` array, and form3 datas are in `$_POST['form3']` array.
Form1 datas are still accessible via regular `$_POST['field']`.

Good luck with your project.